# Powerline Adapters and non-grounded outlets

Tags: electrical, data-wiring, ethernet, internet

I have a powerline adapter connected to an outlet on the main floor of my house. There I have my PS4’s ethernet connected. The other adapter is upstairs where the router is.

Over the last several weeks, I’ve begun to lose connectivity via the ethernet; wi-fi is fine. Ethernet worked great for a long time, but now the disconnection issues are becoming more common.

Now, my powerline is connected to a non-grounded outlet. I know this because I have a power bar connected to the outlet as well, and the grounded light is off.

So my question is, because my powerline isn’t connected to a grounded outlet, is it not getting enough power for the connection to work? Or is it more than likely to be the ethernet cable?

I’m more concerned with the former, as I really don’t want to call an electrician.

Comment: Powerline ___ adapter?  Seem to be missing an adjective.  Are you powering your PS4 over PoE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grounding is a safety measure, it should not affect your connection. Definitely try another ethernet cable.

Now, about that ungrounded outlet..... grounded outlets are a good thing.

Comment: This really depends on the "version" of the powerline adapter.  The older models did not use the ground, but the newer ones that claim higher speeds actually need 3 wires to make that happen.  I think if there is no ground they will fall back to their slower rates, but who knows.

Comment: @JPhi1618  True, but the OP said they worked  great for a long time and just recently started having the problem,  so I'm thinking older version.